# Create multiple containers with templating

Tags: kubernetes

I have a running k8s deployment, with one container.

I want to deploy 10 more containers, with a few differences in the deployment manifest (i.e command launched, container name, ...).

Rather than create 10 more .yml files with the whole deployment, I would prefer use templating. What can I do to achieve this ?

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: myname
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: myname
spec:
  schedule: "*/10 * * * *"
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        metadata:
          labels:
            app.kubernetes.io/name: myname
        spec:
          serviceAccountName: myname
          containers:
            - name: myname
              image: 'mynameimage'
              imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
              command: ["/my/command/to/launch"]
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
```

Comment: You could also do this with a [Helm](https://helm.sh) chart (wrapping this in a `range` loop and using the Go `text/template` language to replace field values), or just make multiple copies of the YAML file and `kubectl apply` the whole directory.

Answer (score 1):

[Kustomize](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/manage-kubernetes-objects/kustomization/) seems to be the go-to tool for templating, composition, multi-environment overriding, etc, in kubernetes configs.  And it's built directly into `kubectl` now as well.

Specifically, I think you can achieve what you want by using the *bases* and *overlays* feature.  Setup a base which contains the common structure and overlays which contain specific overrides.

Answer (score 1):

You can either specify a set of containers to be created you can do that like this:

```sh
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: container1
        image: your-image
      - name: container2
        image: your-image
      - name: container3
        image: your-image
```

and you can repeat that container definition as many times as you want.

The other way around is to use a templating engine like helm/kustomize as mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

Using helm which is a templating engine for Kubernetes manifests you can create your own template by following me through.

> If you have never worked with `helm` you can check the [official docs](https://helm.sh/docs/)
>
> > In order for you to follow make sure you have helm already installed!

#### - create a new chart:

```sh
helm create cowboy-app
```

this will generate a new project for you.

#### - **DELETE EVERYTHING WITHING THE `templates` DIR**

#### - **REMOVE ALL `values.yaml` content**

#### - create a new file `deployment.yaml` in `templates` directory and paste this:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: {{ .Values.appName }}
  labels:
    chart: {{ .Values.appName }}
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: {{ .Values.appName }}
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: {{ .Values.appName }}
    spec:
      containers:
{{ toYaml .Values.images | indent 8 }}
```

#### - in `values.yaml` paste this:

```yaml
appName: cowboy-app
images:
  - name: app-1
    image: image-1
  - name: app-2
    image: image-2
  - name: app-3
    image: image-3
  - name: app-4
    image: image-4
  - name: app-5
    image: image-5    
  - name: app-6
    image: image-6
  - name: app-7
    image: image-7
  - name: app-8
    image: image-8
  - name: app-9
    image: image-9
  - name: app-10
    image: image-10
```

So if you are familiar with helm you can tell that `{{ toYaml .Values.images | indent 10 }}` in the **deployment.yaml** is referring to data specified in **values.yaml** as YAML and by running `helm install release-name /path/to/chart` will generate and deploy a manifest file which is **deployment.yaml** that looks like this:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: cowboy-app
  labels:
    chart: cowboy-app
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: cowboy-app
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: cowboy-app
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: image-1
          name: app-1
        - image: image-2
          name: app-2
        - image: image-3
          name: app-3
        - image: image-4
          name: app-4
        - image: image-5
          name: app-5
        - image: image-6
          name: app-6
        - image: image-7
          name: app-7
        - image: image-8
          name: app-8
        - image: image-9
          name: app-9
        - image: image-10
          name: app-10
```

Answer (score 0):

Either you can use **Helm** or **Kustomize**. Both are templating tools and help you to achieve your goal

Comment: Thanks, I will try both of them.